# Google reCaptcha V2 (Aura component) in Salesforce flow. Everything is working fine except for the challenge tile size

Tags: javascript, salesforce, recaptcha, salesforce-lightning

```
if (eventName==="setHeight") {
                console.log("previous height:: cmp.find(captchaFrame).getElement().height = "+cmp.find("captchaFrame").getElement().height);
                cmp.find("captchaFrame").getElement().height = data;
                console.log("Test:: Height = " +cmp.find("captchaFrame").getElement().height);
            }
```

In the above block of code, I am printing height and I found that even though the height is given as 525 by the google API, in the UI it appears as small and scrollable. I saw some Stackoverflow posts but I was not able to solve my problem. How to override the default UI? Where to code it?

googleRecaptchaController.js

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp, evt, helper) {

        // Reset the isHuman onRendering
        if (cmp.get("v.requiredOnce") === false) {
            cmp.set("v.isHuman", false);
        }        
        // Parsing the originPageURLs
        var allowedURLs = [];

        if (cmp.get("v.originPageURL") != null) {
            var originPageURL = cmp.get("v.originPageURL");
            allowedURLs = originPageURL
                .split(",")
                .map(function(item) {
                    return item.trim();
                });
        }

        // Fetching your Salesforce ORG URLs
        helper.sendRequest(cmp, 'c.fetchBaseURL', {})
            .then($A.getCallback(function(records) {                
                cmp.set("v.allowedURLs", allowedURLs.concat(records));
            }))
            .catch(function(errors) {
                console.error('ERROR: ' + errors);
            });

        // Validating if the recaptcha has been passed successfully 
        cmp.set('v.validate', function() {

            let errorMessage = "Please complete the captcha";

            if (cmp.get("v.requiredMessage")) {
                errorMessage = cmp.get("v.requiredMessage");
            }

            if (cmp.get("v.required") && !cmp.get("v.isHuman")) {
                return { isValid: false, errorMessage: errorMessage};
            }          
            
            return { isValid: true };
        })

        // Listen to the events send from the iframe
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

            // Security Check
            var hasDomain = false;
            var listAllowedURLs = cmp.get("v.allowedURLs");

            if (listAllowedURLs === undefined || listAllowedURLs.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < listAllowedURLs.length; i++) {
                if (listAllowedURLs[i] == event.origin) {
                    hasDomain = true;
                }
            }
            
            if (!hasDomain) {
                return;
            }

            // Splitting up the event array
            var eventName = event.data[0];
            var data = event.data[1];

            // For debug reasons
            console.log(eventName + ', ' + data + ', ' + event.origin);
            
            if (eventName==="setHeight") {
                console.log("previous height:: cmp.find(captchaFrame).getElement().height = "+cmp.find("captchaFrame").getElement().height);
                cmp.find("captchaFrame").getElement().height = data;
                console.log("Test:: Height = " +cmp.find("captchaFrame").getElement().height);
            }
            

            
            if (eventName==="setWidth") {
                cmp.find("captchaFrame").getElement().width = data;
            }
            if (eventName==="Lock") {
                // console.log(" Test: eventName = Lock");
                cmp.set("v.isHuman", false);
            }
            if (eventName==="Unlock") {
                if (cmp.get("v.enableServerSideVerification")) {
                    // console.log(" Test: v.recaptchaResponse = " +data);
                    cmp.set("v.recaptchaResponse", data);
                    // Create the server side apex verification
                    var params = {"recaptchaResponse" : cmp.get("v.recaptchaResponse"), "recaptchaSecretKey" : cmp.get("v.secretKey")};
                    helper.sendRequest(cmp, 'c.isVerified', params)
                    .then($A.getCallback(function(records) {
                        // If verified positive                    
                        if (records === true) {

                            // Let the animation wait a bit to fade out if required once
                            if (cmp.get("v.requiredOnce") === true) {
                                // console.log(" Test: Wait for animation");
                                window.setTimeout(
                                    $A.getCallback(function() {
                                        cmp.set("v.isHuman", true);
                                    }), 500
                                );
                            } else {
                                // else do it directly
                                cmp.set("v.isHuman", true);
                            }
                           
                        }
                    }))
                    .catch(function(errors) {
                        // console.error('ERROR: ' + errors);
                    });

                } else {
                    cmp.set("v.isHuman", true);
                }       
            }

        }, false);
    },

})
```

googleRecaptcha.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="GoogleRecaptchaHandler" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="isHuman" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="originPageURL" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="required" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="requiredMessage" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="requiredOnce" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="recaptchaResponse" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="enableServerSideVerification" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="siteKey" type="String" default="<mykey>-"/>
    <aura:attribute name="secretKey" type="String" default="myKey" />
    <aura:attribute name="allowedURLs" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="frameTitle" type="String" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <!-- In case requiredOnce is set to true and the captcha has not been verified, display it -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.requiredOnce == true}">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isHuman == false}">
            <iframe aura:id="captchaFrame" src="{!$Resource.Google_Recaptcha + '?sitekey=' + v.siteKey + '&#38;title=' + v.frameTitle}" width="350" height="100" style="border:0px; overflow:hidden;" />
        </aura:if>
        
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <iframe aura:id="captchaFrame" src="{!$Resource.Google_Recaptcha + '?sitekey=' + v.siteKey + '&#38;title=' + v.frameTitle}" width="350" height="100" style="border:0px; overflow:hidden;" />
        </aura:set>   
    </aura:if>
    
</aura:component>
```

[As you can see, sometimes the challenge tiles are compressed. i want them to expand so users doesn't have to scroll down to finish the challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epUJH.png)